# java compilation error: method inside method

Tags: java, boolean

I got the following error run my code

> Line: 18 illegal start of expression
>
> Line: 18 ';' expected

this means there is code in 18 line is not proper written(public boolean Ap(){....}) but i think it is proper i am not sure so can someone tell me what is wrong

here is a part of code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrimeExample{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int i =0;
        int m=0;
        int flag=0;
        int k =10;//number of terms
        int d =210;// common difference    
        int n=2;//it is the number to be checked 
        m=n/2;   
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList( );    
        int number=0;
        boolean b= false;
        while( Ap() == false){
            d++;
            list.clear();
            public boolean Ap(){}
        }
    }
}
```

you can find the working code here

http://www.browxy.com/SavedCode/231130

NOTE:- I have remove some part of code without error so as to safeguard some part of the code

Comment: Your Ap() method does not return anything. It has to return either true or false for the code to work. Btw: while(!Ap()) will do the job, you don't have to compare with false explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `public boolean Ap(){}` method:

1. It should be outside the `main` method.
2. It should be `static` (since it is accessed from a static context).
3. It should have a return statement (it must return `true` or `false`).